# Loading A STv4 Template From a Jar

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, stringtemplate-4

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to migrate my code to use org.stringtemplate.v4 . I have a single template file in a 'templates' folder under src/main/resources. Nothing fancy going on. I just need to load the template, set a few attributes, and pass it along in my html response. The problem is, the template is getting bundled into the deployed jar, which means I can't do a normal classpath lookup. Usually in a case like this, I would use an InputStream, but I can't find any way of doing that with the available constructors for ST and STGroup. Does anyone know how to do this? is there an easier way I'm just overlooking?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupDir("templates");
        ST template = group.getInstanceOf("smartSubmitResponse");
        template.add("errors", results.exceptions.asMap());
        template.add("plannedDates", results.plannedDates);
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).header("smartSubmitFileUrl", url)
                .header("errors", errorHeaders.toString()).entity(template.toString()).build();
```

Currently, it is failing with a null pointer exception since template is not being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I needed to use org.stringtemplate.v4.STRawGroupDir since my template was using the older format with no wrapping characters. My result ended up looking like this:

```
STGroup group = new STRawGroupDir("templates",'$','$');
ST template = group.getInstanceOf("smartSubmitResponse");
```